# Suddenly, I'm getting a Fatal error: Cannot redeclare

Tags: php

I'm getting a strange error on a piece of code that used to work perfectly before, but suddenly started pushing out errors...

That's the releavant code:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
}
return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

function getFileList($dir)
{
   // array to hold return value
$retval = array();

// add trailing slash if missing
if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

// open pointer to directory and read list of files
$d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  // skip hidden files
  if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
  if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
    $retval[] = array(
      "name" => "$dir$entry/",
      "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"),
      "size" => 0,
      "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
    );
  } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
    $retval[] = array(
      "name" => "$dir$entry",
      "type" => mime_content_type("$dir$entry"),
      "size" => filesize("$dir$entry"),
      "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry")
    );
  }
}
$d->close();

uasort($retval, 'cmp');
return $retval;
}
```

and the error I'm getting is:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare cmp() (previously declared in /store/cpanel/home/martinak/public_html/modules/mod_supersized/mod_supersized.php:3) in /store/cpanel/home/martinak/public_html/modules/mod_supersized/mod_supersized.php on line 8

Now, the code above does start on line 3 as stated in the error, but line 8 containst just the "}".

As stated the code used to work, it hasn't been changed, and just stopped working after months. Could it be a server configuration problem? Any ideas?

Thanks!
S.

UPDATE:

I'm so sorry guys. I just realized my client messed up my code. I hate when people try to fix things without having the knowledge to do so and then cry for help when they mess it up.

I apologize for wasting your time, I hope you'll forgive me.

Comment: Sounds like you need to `require_once()` somewhere rather than just `require()`.

Comment: Either that, or you are declaring this function inside another which is called more than once, or in some iterative structure.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've included this file twice. Just switch from `require()`/`include()` to `require_once()`/`include_once()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the cmp() function TWO (or more) times. maybe you included THIS piece of code more than one time...

Answer (score 1):

maybe you use `require` in other files and there exists cmp function already

Comment: Thanks. I thought that too, but I tried changing the function name to something different and I still got the same error. And, as I said, it worked, and there was no change to the code whatsoever... It's really making me insane :P

Answer (score 1):

The only possible explanation is that you are including the same file more than once. Change your include or require to include_once and require_once.